# Pygame sound object created but not played

Tags: python, pygame

During the gameplay of the game there should be sounds playing for each correct or incorrect click. The debug says it loaded in but it doesn't play the sound. please help

```py
SOUNDS_METAL = ["assets/sounds/metal_1.ogg",
                "assets/sounds/metal_2.ogg"]

SOUNDS_GLASS = ["assets/sounds/glass_1.ogg",
                "assets/sounds/glass_2.ogg"]

SOUNDS_PLASTIC = ["assets/sounds/plastic_1.ogg",
                  "assets/sounds/plastic_2.ogg"]

SOUNDS_PAPER = ["assets/sounds/paper_1.ogg",
                "assets/sounds/paper_2.ogg"]

SOUNDS_FX = ["assets/sounds/fx_pop.ogg",
             "assets/sounds/fx_error.ogg"]

SOUNDS = [SOUNDS_METAL, SOUNDS_GLASS, SOUNDS_PLASTIC, SOUNDS_PAPER, SOUNDS_FX]
.
.
.
```

```py
def collision_detector(mouse_pos, target, points, bin_type):
    """checkt wether or not the click is inside the target area"""
    if target[0][0] < mouse_pos[0] < target[0][1]:
        if target[1][0] < mouse_pos[1] < target[1][1]:
            debuginfo("CORRECT HIT")
            points += 1
            debuginfo(f"POINTS: {points}")
            sound_effectplayer(bin_type)
            main(points)
.
.
.
def new_rubbish_maker():
    """creates the ryubbish object"""
    global MAIN_RUBBISH
    MAIN_RUBBISH = random.choice(ALL_RUBBISH)
    sound_effectplayer("new_item")

def sound_effectplayer(object_type):
    """plays the sound effects"""
    global sound_effect
    debuginfo(f"MUSIC OBJECT TYPE: {object_type}")
    if object_type == "metal":
        sound_effect = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(SOUNDS_METAL))
        debuginfo(f"EFFECT: {sound_effect}")
    elif object_type == "plastic":
        sound_effect = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(SOUNDS_PLASTIC))
        debuginfo(f"EFFECT: {sound_effect}")
    elif object_type == "paper":
        sound_effect = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(SOUNDS_PLASTIC))
        debuginfo(f"EFFECT: {sound_effect}")
    elif object_type == "glass":
        sound_effect = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(SOUNDS_GLASS))
        debuginfo(f"EFFECT: {sound_effect}")
    elif object_type == "bad":
        sound_effect = pygame.mixer.Sound(SOUNDS_FX[1])
        debuginfo(f"EFFECT: {sound_effect}")
    elif object_type == "new_item":
        sound_effect = pygame.mixer.Sound(SOUNDS_FX[0])
    sound_effect.play()
```

full code : https://gitlab.com/Gote/game

Answer (score 0):

Add
`pygame.mixer.init()`
To the very top of `sound_effectplayer` function, so that it will look like this:

```
def sound_effectplayer(object_type):
    pygame.mixer.init()
    . . .
```